# Automated test for Flask server won't recognize HTML tags in rendered templates (Python)

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm really new in Stack Overflow (and coding in general for that matter). Our final assignment for our Web Programming period in college is to make a Flask server which will recover info from the openFDA API (a compilation of commercial drug labels). It has to retreive the drugs' names/manufacturers/medical warnings... and display them in a HTML list, which then I render with the "render_template" command .

The code for the server will be tested by a program our teacher gave us, and we need to pass all tests in order to not fail the whole subject. Currently I only have three tests left to beat,but I can't figure them out.

I have a slight idea of what's going on however. I think the test doesn't recognize the tags "li" tags of the elements of the list, thus thinking the list is just empty. I've tried to solve this, but I've had no luck so far.

I would be very grateful if you guys could give me a solution in two days or less. If I fail this I'll have to pay a ton of money for next year's tuition, so, yeah...

Here's my server:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import Response
from flask import redirect
from functools import wraps
import http.client
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

MAIN_INPUT = "api.fda.gov"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'http-client'}
DEBUG = True

main_conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(MAIN_INPUT)

@app.route ("/searchDrug", methods = ['GET']) # Busca hasta 100 medicamentos con el principio activo especificado
def getActIng():

    name = request.args['active_ingredient']
    limit = request.args['limit']

    try:
        openfda_input = '/drug/label.json?search=active_ingredient:{acting}&limit={lim}'.format(acting=name,lim=limit)
        main_conn.request('GET', openfda_input, None, headers)
    except:
        print("Error")
        exit(1)

    data_stage1 = main_conn.getresponse()

    data_stage2 = data_stage1.read()
    main_conn.close()

    data_final = json.loads(data_stage2)

    main_dict = data_final['results']
    name_list=[]
    for elem in main_dict:
        if 'brand_name' in elem['openfda']:
            name_list.append("<li>" + str(elem['openfda']['brand_name']).strip("['']") + "</li>")
        else:
            name_list.append("<li>Desconocido</li>")

    name_str = str(''.join(name_list))

    def print_ul(elements):
        print("<ul>")
        for s in elements:
            ul = "<li>" + str(s) + "</li>"
        print(ul)
        print("</ul>")

    html_str = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <p>Nombres comerciales disponibles para medicamentos con {r} como principio activo en openFDA:</p>
        <p>Mostrando {l} resultados</p>
        <ul>
        <p>{mans}</p>
        </ul>
        </body>
        </html>
        """

    with open("templates/getActIng.html","w") as main_output:
        main_output.write("")
        html_str_mod = html_str.format(r=name, l=limit, mans=name_str)
        main_output.write(html_str_mod)

    print(name_str)

    return render_template('getActIng.html')

@app.route ("/searchCompany", methods = ['GET']) # Busca hasta 100 medicamentos fabricados por la empresa especificada
def getComName():

    company_name = request.args['company']
    limit = request.args['limit']

    try:
        openfda_input = '/drug/label.json?search=manufacturer_name:{comnam}&limit={lim}'.format(comnam=company_name,lim=limit)
        main_conn.request('GET', openfda_input, None, headers)
    except:
        print("Error")
        exit(1)

    data_stage1 = main_conn.getresponse()

    data_stage2 = data_stage1.read()
    main_conn.close()

    data_final = json.loads(data_stage2)

    main_dict = data_final['results']
    med_list=[]
    for elem in main_dict:
        if 'manufacturer_name' in elem['openfda']:
            med_list.append("<li>" + str(elem['openfda']['brand_name']).strip("['']") + "</li>")
        else:
            med_list.append("<li>Desconocido</li>")

    med_str = str(''.join(med_list))

    html_str = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <p>Medicamentos fabricados por {r} en openFDA:</p>
        <p>Mostrando {l} resultados</p>
        <ul>
        <p>{meds}</p>
        </ul>
        </body>
        </html>
        """

    with open("templates/getComName.html","w") as main_output:
        html_str_mod = html_str.format(r=company_name,l=limit,meds=med_str)
        main_output.write(html_str_mod)

    return render_template('getComName.html')

@app.route ("/listDrugs", methods = ['GET']) # Devuelve una cantidad aleatoria de medicamentos
def getListDrugs():

    limit = request.args['limit']

    try:
        openfda_input = '/drug/label.json?limit={amount}'.format(amount=limit)
        main_conn.request('GET', openfda_input, None, headers)
    except:
        print("Error")
        exit(1)

    data_stage1 = main_conn.getresponse()

    data_stage2 = data_stage1.read()
    main_conn.close()

    data_final = json.loads(data_stage2)

    main_dict = data_final['results']
    ran_list=[]
    for elem in main_dict:
        if 'brand_name' in elem['openfda']:
            ran_list.append("<li>" + str(elem['openfda']['brand_name']).strip("['']") + "</li>")
        else:
            ran_list.append("<li>Desconocido</li>")

    ran_str = str(''.join(ran_list))

    html_str = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <p>Nombres comerciales de {r} medicamentos de openFDA:</p>
        <p>Mostrando {l} resultados</p>
        <ul>
        <p>{rans}</p>
        </ul>
        </body>
        </html>
        """

    with open("templates/getListDrugs.html","w") as main_output:
        html_str_mod = html_str.format(r=limit,l=limit, rans=ran_str)
        main_output.write(html_str_mod)

    return render_template('getListDrugs.html')

@app.route ("/listCompanies", methods = ['GET']) # Devuelve una cantidad especificada de empresas con uno de sus productos
def getListCom():

    limit = request.args['limit']

    try:
        openfda_input = '/drug/label.json?limit={amount}'.format(amount=limit)
        main_conn.request('GET', openfda_input, None, headers)
    except:
        print("Error")
        exit(1)

    data_stage1 = main_conn.getresponse()

    data_stage2 = data_stage1.read()
    main_conn.close()

    data_final = json.loads(data_stage2)

    main_dict = data_final['results']
    com_list=[]
    for elem in main_dict:
        if 'manufacturer_name' in elem['openfda']:
            com_list.append("<li>" + str(elem['openfda']['manufacturer_name']).strip("['']") + "</li>")
        else:
            com_list.append("<li>Desconocido</li>")

    com_str = str(''.join(com_list))

    html_str = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <p>Nombres de {r} fabricantes (y sus respectivos productos) de openFDA:</p>
        <p>Mostrando {l} resultados</p>
        <ul>
        <p>{prod}</p>
        </ul>
        </body>
        </html>
        """

    with open("templates/getListCom.html","w") as main_output:
        html_str_mod = html_str.format(r=limit,l=limit, prod=com_str)
        main_output.write(html_str_mod)

    return render_template('getListCom.html')

@app.route ("/listWarnings", methods = ['GET']) # Devuelve una cantidad aleatoria de medicamentos
def getListWar():

    limit = request.args['limit']

    try:
        openfda_input = '/drug/label.json?limit={amount}'.format(amount=limit)
        main_conn.request('GET', openfda_input, None, headers)
    except:
        print("Error")
        exit(1)

    data_stage1 = main_conn.getresponse()

    data_stage2 = data_stage1.read()
    main_conn.close()

    data_final = json.loads(data_stage2)

    main_dict = data_final['results']
    war_list=[]
    for elem in main_dict:
        if 'warnings' in elem:
            war_list.append("<li>" + str(elem['warnings']).strip("['']") + "</li>")
        else:
            war_list.append("<li>Desconocido</li>")

    war_str = str(''.join(war_list))

    html_str = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <p>Advertencias:</p>
        <p>Mostrando {l} resultados</p>
        <ul>
        <p>{wars}</p>
        </ul>
        </body>
        </html>
        """

    with open("templates/getListWars.html","w") as main_output:
        html_str_mod = html_str.format(l=limit, wars=war_str)
        main_output.write(html_str_mod)

    return render_template('getListWars.html')

@app.route('/secret', methods = ['GET'])
def getSecret():
    return Response(
    'Could not verify your access level for that URL.\n'
    'You have to login with proper credentials', 401,
    {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Not Authorized"'})

@app.route('/redirect', methods = ['GET'])
def getRedirect():
    return redirect("http://127.0.0.1:8000/", code=302)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    return """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="es">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>OpenFDA-project</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form action = "listDrugs" method="get">
          <input type="submit" value="Listar fármacos">
            Limite: <input type="text" name="limit" value="">
        </form>
        <form action = "listCompanies" method="get">
          <input type="submit" value="Listar empresas">
            Limite: <input type="text" name="limit" value="">
        </form>
        <form action = "searchDrug" method="get">
          <input type="submit" value="Buscar fármaco">
            Campo: <input type="text" name="active_ingredient" value="">
            Limite Drug: <input type="text" name="limit" value="">
        </form>
        <form action = "searchCompany" method="get">
          <input type="submit" value="Buscar empresas">
            Campo: <input type="text" name="company" value="">
            Limite Com: <input type="text" name="limit" value="">
        </form>
        <form action = "listWarnings" method="get">
          <input type="submit" value="Advertencias">
            Limite: <input type="text" name="limit" value="">
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
        """

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run('127.0.0.1', port = 8000, debug = True, use_reloader = False)
```

Here's the automated test:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import threading
import time
import unittest

import requests

from html.parser import HTMLParser

PYTHON_CMD = os.path.abspath(sys.executable)

class OpenFDAHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.actions_list = []
        self.forms_number = 0
        self.items_number = 0

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        # print("Encountered a start tag:", tag)
        if tag == "form":
            self.forms_number += 1
            for attr in attrs:
                if attr[0] == 'action':
                    self.actions_list.append(attr[1])
        elif tag == "li":
            self.items_number += 1


    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        # print("Encountered an end tag :", tag)
        pass


    def handle_data(self, data):
        # print("Encountered some data  :", data)
        pass


class WebServer(threading.Thread):
    """ Thread to start the web server """

    def run(self):
        # Start the web server in a thread. It will be killed once tests have finished
        cmd = [PYTHON_CMD, 'server.py']
        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        TestOpenFDA.WEBSERVER_PROC = proc
        outs, errs = proc.communicate()
        errs_str = errs.decode("utf8")
        if 'Address already in use' in errs_str:
            TestOpenFDA.PORT_BUSY = True
            return

class TestOpenFDA(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Automatic testing for OpenFDA web server main features """
    WEBSERVER_PROC = None
    PORT_BUSY = False
    TEST_PORT = 8000
    TEST_DRUG = 'Aspirin'
    TEST_COMPANY = 'Bayer'
    TEST_ACTIONS = ['listDrugs', 'searchDrug', 'listCompanies', 'searchCompany', 'listWarnings']

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        """ Start the web server to be tested """
        WebServer().start()
        # Wait for web sever init code
        time.sleep(1)
        if cls.PORT_BUSY:
            raise RuntimeError("PORT BUSY")

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        """ Shutdown the webserver """
        cls.WEBSERVER_PROC.kill()

    def test_web_server_init(self):
        resp = requests.get('http://localhost:' + str(self.TEST_PORT))
        # print(resp.text)
        parser = OpenFDAHTMLParser()
        parser.feed(resp.text)
        # Remove listWarnings that it is not in the basic specification
        self.TEST_ACTIONS.remove('listWarnings')
        try:
            parser.actions_list.remove('listWarnings')
        except ValueError:
            # The form does not include this option
            pass
        self.assertEqual(len(parser.actions_list), 4)
        self.assertEqual(set(self.TEST_ACTIONS), set(parser.actions_list))
        self.TEST_ACTIONS.append('listWarnings')

    def test_web_server_init_warnings(self):
        # In the complete project a listWarnings is included
        resp = requests.get('http://localhost:' + str(self.TEST_PORT))
        # print(resp.text)
        parser = OpenFDAHTMLParser()
        parser.feed(resp.text)
        self.assertEqual(parser.forms_number, 5)
        self.assertEqual(set(self.TEST_ACTIONS), set(parser.actions_list))

    def test_list_drugs(self):
        url = 'http://localhost:' + str(self.TEST_PORT)
        url += '/listDrugs?limit=10'
        resp = requests.get(url)
        parser = OpenFDAHTMLParser()
        parser.feed(resp.text)
        self.assertEqual(parser.items_number, 10)

    def test_list_drugs_limit(self):
        url = 'http://localhost:' + str(self.TEST_PORT)
        url += '/listDrugs?limit=22'
        resp = requests.get(url)
        parser = OpenFDAHTMLParser()
        parser.feed(resp.text)
        self.assertEqual(parser.items_number, 22)

    def test_search_drug(self):
        url = 'http://localhost:' + str(self.TEST_PORT)
        url += '/searchDrug?active_ingredient="%s"' % self.TEST_DRUG
        resp = requests.get(url)
        # print(resp.text)
        parser = OpenFDAHTMLParser()
        parser.feed(resp.text)
        self.assertEqual(parser.items_number, 10)

    def test_list_companies(self):
        url = 'http://localhost:' + str(self.TEST_PORT)
        url += '/listCompanies?limit=10'
        resp = requests.get(url)
        # print(resp.text)
        parser = OpenFDAHTMLParser()
        parser.feed(resp.text)
        self.assertEqual(parser.items_number, 10)

    def test_list_warnings(self):
        url = 'http://localhost:' + str(self.TEST_PORT)
        url += '/listWarnings?limit=10'
        resp = requests.get(url)
        # print(resp.text)
        parser = OpenFDAHTMLParser()
        parser.feed(resp.text)
        self.assertEqual(parser.items_number, 10)

    def test_search_company(self):
        url = 'http://localhost:' + str(self.TEST_PORT)
        url += '/searchCompany?company=' + self.TEST_COMPANY
        resp = requests.get(url)
        # print(resp.text)
        parser = OpenFDAHTMLParser()
        parser.feed(resp.text)
        self.assertEqual(parser.items_number, 10)

    def test_not_found(self):
        url = 'http://localhost:' + str(self.TEST_PORT)
        url += '/not_exists_resource'
        resp = requests.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 404)

    def test_redirect(self):
        url = 'http://localhost:' + str(self.TEST_PORT)
        url += '/redirect'
        resp = requests.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)

    def test_auth(self):
        url = 'http://localhost:' + str(self.TEST_PORT)
        url += '/secret'
        resp = requests.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 401)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main(warnings='ignore')
```

And here's the traceback I get in Windows Command Prompt (I know, I know, I'll switch to some Linux distro the moment I get myself a new hard drive XD):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V8ys.jpg

Comment: There are a few strange things here, but the immediate cause is probably that this really really isn't how you create output in Flask. Have a look at the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Comment: Also note, Flask has a built-in way of [running a test server](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/) which you can make requests to, no need for all this mucking around with subprocesses.

Comment: I know this test is kind of dumb, but this is how our teacher is going to evaluate our work, no matter what we say. I've already told him the test seems a little unnecesary, but there's nothing we can do about it.

Comment: Fair enough. But go back to the Flask docs and learn how to produce output from a handler function. You should absolutely not be writing out templates from Python code and then reading them with render_template, that's not how it works at all.

Comment: The thing is, I've tried to output the HTML chunk of text itself, without storing it in a template, like "return (insert HTML block here)". It doesn't work either. I stand by my point that the test just doesn't recongnize the list tags of the list elements